# Error when attempting to install Go-SQL-Driver: undefined: syscall.Conn

Tags: go, driver, ubuntu-16.04

On Ubuntu 16.04 with go version 1.8, when executing the command

```
go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

I got this error:

```
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/conncheck.go:29: undefined: syscall.Conn
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Which version of Go do you have installed?

Comment: go version go1.8 linux/amd64

Comment: *"How can I resolve this problem?"* by upgrading to at least 1.9. https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Conn you can see the version number on the far right, it indicates when that type was added.

Comment: I have resolve this problem by upgrading the version. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go-MySQL-Driver [only supports Go 1.9](https://github.com/Go-SQL-Driver/MySQL/#requirements) or later. You are using Go 1.8, and the syscall.Conn interface was [only introduced in Go 1.9](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#syscall).

You should upgrade to a later version of Go on your system, or use an alternative SQL driver that supports an earlier version of Go.